# Visual Studio shortcut to navigate to class of variable

Tags: visual-studio

Usually it is a simply as clicking on <kbd>F12</kbd> on the declaration class type of a variable.

However with increased usage of the `var` keyword, I was wondering if visual studio had a shortcut to navigate to the class of a variable directly.  Just thought it would save some time instead of using 'ctrl+,' or looking up the method that returned the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` should work the same as any type.  You can <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + LeftClick or hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to be taken to the type definition for the inferred type of `var`.

Comment: omg... how is it that I have never even attempted to try for over 3 years.  thanks :)