# Shortcut for "jump to definition" on lambda parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looking for a shortcut to jump to the (class) definition of a variable, in the following context.

```
.Select(it|em => item.DoSomething())
```

where the `|` is the cursor.

I know that F12 works with `var`, but what can I do in the above situation?

```
v|ar something = Get.Something(); // F12 takes you to class Something { }
```

Comment: Related to but different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980289/visual-studio-shortcut-to-navigate-to-class-of-variable#:~:text=Usually%20it%20is%20a%20simply,class%20type%20of%20a%20variable.